# How to waterproof walk out basement

Tags: basement, moisture, cinderblock

My mother's house is built on top of a hill that drops off at the rear. The front half of house is over a tall crawl space, the back half is an 8' high finished walk out basement with drywall and has HVAC connected from the upstairs. All foundation walls are cinder block.

No water leaks in the basement but I did notice some of the blocks on the side exterior walls of basement are darker indicating some water seepage into the blocks.

I'm confused about the pros/cons of using a product like Drylok on the interior of these walls. I think this condition is mainly from the extreme rains we've recently experienced but want to keep any damage from occurring if the rains continue in the future.

There is a French drain on one side of the house. The soil is mainly clay but I haven't seen any standing or pooled water on the lawn.  (This is a rural location where very few houses have basements so I haven't found any experts locally.)

Am I being overly cautious or is there a product to use on the interior that would help?

Comment: Got any pictures?

Comment: How would you apply Drylok to interior walls in a finished basement?